# Shared foreign keys without duplication of entries?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Sorry for the beginner question.

I have an Outputs table:

| ID | value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | x |
| 1 | y |
| 2 | z |

And an Inputs table that is linked to the Outputs through the `outputsID`:

| ID | outputsID | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | A |
| 1 | 1 | B |
| 2 | 1 | C |
| 3 | 2 | B |
| 4 | 2 | C |

Assuming that multiple outputs have at least one shared input (in this example `outputID` 1,3 and 2,4 are the same), is there a way to avoid the duplication of entries in my Inputs table (`inputID` 3 and 4)?

Answer (score 0):

The 'normal' answer to your question is no.  Rows 1 and 2 address output 1, and Rows 3 and 4 address output 2.  They aren't duplicates and each reflect something distinct.

So if you are a beginner, I would say you shouldn't want to get rid of these rows.

That said, there are some more advanced techniques.  For example, you could have the OutputsID column be an array with multiple values.  This is harder, more complex, and non-standard.